# Prove that $\frac{{S^1} \times [0,1]}{S^1\times \{1\}}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{D}^2$

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Prove that  $\frac{{S^1} \times [0,1]}{S^1\times \{1\}}$  is  homeomorphic to $\mathbb{D}^2?$

My attempt :I know that  ${S^1} \times [0,1]$ is regular cylinder and $S^1\times \{1\} \cong S^1$

We know that $\mathbb{D}^2$ is a contractible  so there exist a map $f:\mathbb{D^2}  \to  {x_0}$ and $g:{x_0} \to \mathbb{D}^2$ such that
$fg\cong id_{x_0}$  and $gf\cong id_{\mathbb{D}^2} \implies f  $  is  homeomorphism.

Therefore ,i think  $$\frac{{S^1} \times [0,1]}{S^1\times \{1\}}  \cong \{x_0\}$$

Comment: Homotopy equivalence is not homeomorphism. $f$ is not a homeomorphism: it's not bijective.

Comment: Just think of polar coordainates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is a topological space, and $A$ is a subspace of $X$, then $X/A$ is homeomorphic to a space $Y$ if there is a quotient map $f : X \to Y$ such that $$(\forall x_1,x_2 \in X) \quad f(x_1) = f(x_2) \iff x_1 = x_2 \textrm{ or } x_1,x_2 \in A.$$
In your case, let $X = S^1 \times [0,1]$, $A = S^1 \times \{1\}$, $Y = D^2$, and consider $f : X \to Y$ such that $f(z,t) = (1-t)z$ for all $z \in S^1$ and $t \in [0,1]$.

Comment: (However, it is true in this particular case since the domain is compact.)

Comment: @hunter Oh, that's right. My bad. It's fixed now.